# displaying array to html page

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code. I want to be able to display the matching results of the star rating, based on users input, to an HTML page. How can I do this?

```js
class Hotel {
  constructor(name, stars, distance, wifi, pool, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stars = stars;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.wifi = wifi;
    this.pool = pool;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

var hotels = [];
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grand", "5", "0.5", "yes", "no", "190"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Plaza", "4", "1", "yes", "yes", "70"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lord Miliburn", "4", "5", "yes", "no", "65"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grange", "3", "1", "yes", "no", "57"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Windmill", "1", "10", "no", "no", "5"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Excel", "3", "0.5", "yes", "no", "56"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Ritz", "2", "5", "yes", "no", "14"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Victoria", "4", "0.5", "yes", "no", "80"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("Pheonix House", "4", "1", "yes", "No", "72"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lodge", "2", "1", "no", "no", "25"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Sanctum", "5", "2", "yes", "yes", "180"));

const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
  return hotel.stars >= userStar;
  document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "write me to the screen";
});
console.log(matchingStars);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes code is working but i want to be able to display the results to a HTML page using DOM

Comment: "display the results" is pretty vague. There are a lot of ways to display this information. Loop through the matchingStars array and insert the data you want in whatever format you want to the DOM. Also, code after a `return` statement is never going to be run.

Answer (score 0):

TO achieve expected result, change userStar to number by parseInt

```
hotel.stars >= parseInt(userStar);
```

Create Li element and add to UL element , if stars are equal to or greater than useStar

```
class Hotel {
  constructor(name, stars, distance, wifi, pool, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stars = stars;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.wifi = wifi;
    this.pool = pool;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

var hotels = [];
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grand", "5", "0.5", "yes", "no", "190"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Plaza", "4", "1", "yes", "yes", "70"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lord Miliburn", "4", "5", "yes", "no", "65"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grange", "3", "1", "yes", "no", "57"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Windmill", "1", "10", "no", "no", "5"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Excel", "3", "0.5", "yes", "no", "56"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Ritz", "2", "5", "yes", "no", "14"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Victoria", "4", "0.5", "yes", "no", "80"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("Pheonix House", "4", "1", "yes", "No", "72"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lodge", "2", "1", "no", "no", "25"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Sanctum", "5", "2", "yes", "yes", "180"));

const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
  console.log(userStar)
  var li = document.createElement('LI')
  if(hotel.stars >= parseInt(userStar)){
         li.innerHTML = hotel.stars >= parseInt(userStar) ? hotel.name :''
         document.getElementById("insert").appendChild(li);
     }

  return hotel.stars >= parseInt(userStar);

});
console.log(matchingStars);
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BxaxXe

Answer (score 0):

Probably is not the best option, but if you just need to print the names, you can replace this:

```
const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function (hotel) {
    return hotel.stars >= userStar;
    document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "write me to the screen";
});
console.log(matchingStars);
```

for this:

```
window.onload = () => {
    const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
    const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function (hotel) {
        return hotel.stars >= userStar;
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < matchingStars.length; i++)
        document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML += matchingStars[i].name + "<br>";
}
```

The function in window.onload is necessary, otherwise you'll get a message error while trying to set innerHTML of null element.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is causing the line that updates innerHTML to never be evaluated. If you switch the lines around then your "insert" element will be populated with "write me to the screen". I've also changed your `=` to `+=` so that it lists each iteration instead of just the final one.

If you want to write specific fields then you need to reference the hotel object that's being iterated over (or simply pass back the array and map it later):

```
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
    document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML += hotel.name;
    return hotel.stars >= userStar;
});
```

You can also use template literals which allow you to reference values without using concatenation:

```
document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML += `${hotel.name}: ${hotel.stars}<br>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement for placing content in `insert` id is never reached due to it being after your `return` statement. Is this an idea of what you're looking for? It's a very rough draft for outputting the data (no `CSS`, using old `table` techniques, etc, which I wouldn't advise, but used for the sake of example)..

```js
class Hotel {
  constructor(name, stars, distance, wifi, pool, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stars = stars;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.wifi = wifi;
    this.pool = pool;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

var buildHTML = function(matchingStars) {
  var builderString = "";

  for (var star in matchingStars) {
    var hotel = matchingStars[star];
    builderString += "<td>";
    builderString += "Name: " + hotel.name + "<br/>";
    builderString += "Stars: " + hotel.stars + "<br/>";
    builderString += "Distance: " + hotel.distance + "<br/>";
    builderString += "Wifi: " + hotel.wifi + "<br/>";
    builderString += "Pool: " + hotel.pool + "<br/>";
    builderString += "Price: $" + hotel.price + "<br/>";
    builderString += "</td>";
  }

  return builderString;
};

var hotels = [];
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grand", "5", "0.5", "yes", "no", "190"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Plaza", "4", "1", "yes", "yes", "70"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lord Miliburn", "4", "5", "yes", "no", "65"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grange", "3", "1", "yes", "no", "57"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Windmill", "1", "10", "no", "no", "5"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Excel", "3", "0.5", "yes", "no", "56"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Ritz", "2", "5", "yes", "no", "14"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Victoria", "4", "0.5", "yes", "no", "80"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("Pheonix House", "4", "1", "yes", "No", "72"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lodge", "2", "1", "no", "no", "25"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Sanctum", "5", "2", "yes", "yes", "180"));

const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
  return hotel.stars >= userStar;
});
//console.log(matchingStars);

var htmlString = buildHTML(matchingStars);

document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='5' border='1'><tr>" + htmlString + "</tr></table>";
```

```html
<div id="insert">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is an array of objects, and after the filter is run a simple for loop will iterate over the array and you can specify which info to return and add to innerHTML.

```
   const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
    const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel) {
      return hotel.stars >= userStar;
    });
    let data = ' '
    for(let i = 0; i < matchingStars.length; i++){
        data += ' ' + matchingStars[i].name
     document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = data
     }
    console.log(matchingStars);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DevGru6/aL71azky/21/)

and also use template literals for that data [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)